Best approach to convert application from AngularJS to React/Typescript micro frontend
We have monolithic AngularJS App and now we are going to migrate to ReactJS Micro Frontend App. In the AngularJS App, we have total 64 html pages. Based on API response which contains LayoutId, we render 1 HTML page per request (Page is dynamic). Below is the code snippet.
var layouts = { 
101: {
template: require('./layout-101.html'),
searchOptions: [
  {
    code: 'defaultSearch',
    value: 'Default Search'
  },
  {
    code: 'LastNameSearch',
    value: 'Last Name Search'
  }     
]
},
102: {
template: require('./layout-102.html'),
searchOptions: [
  {
    code: 'defaultSearch',
    value: 'Default Search'
  },
  {
    code: 'outOfStateSearch',
    value: 'Out of State Search'
  }
 ]   
}
......
......
......
}

In Controller
 function showLayout(layoutId) {
 showForm.searchOptions = LayoutsService.getSearchOptionsForLayout(layoutId);  
 showForm.currentLayout = LayoutsService.getLayoutKey(layoutId);
 showForm.layout = _.cloneDeep(LayoutsService.getScopeDataForLayout(layoutId));
}

function getLayout(layoutId) {
return layouts[layoutId] || layouts.unknown;
}

In Service, LayoutsService has few methods to call API.
 function getLayout(layoutId) {
 return layouts[layoutId] || layouts.unknown;
 }
 .....
 .....
 .....

Now I need to convert these pages to ReactJS, How I could achieve this with minimal code. I mean based on layoutId I need to render 1 page out of 64 pages. What will be the best approach?

I understand that your 64 html pages are slightly different and are base on slightly different data, but are orchestrated by the same AngularJS controller.
Unfortunately, with React you can't reproduce this logic. However, you can create 64 components with code and values props:
export function Layout101({searchOptions}) {
    return (
      <div>your HTML layout</div>
    );
};

Then you can create the layouts variables like this:
const layouts = {
    101: (
      <Layout101 searchOptions={[
        {
          code: 'defaultSearch',
          value: 'Default Search'
        },
        {
          code: 'LastNameSearch',
          value: 'Last Name Search'
        }     
      ]}
      />
    ),
    102: (
      <Layout102 searchOptions={[
        {
          code: 'outOfStateSearch',
          value: 'Out of State Search'
        },
        {
          code: 'defaultSearch',
          value: 'Default Search'
        }     
      ]}
      />
    ),
};

Then you render the correct layout like this:
export function ShowLayout({layoutId}) {
    const layouts = { see code above ... };
    return <>{ layouts[layoutId] }</> || <LayoutUnknown />;
}

